# Wilson Score for 1-5 star rating in sql

Tags: mysql, rating-system

I found [this](http://www.onextrapixel.com/2015/09/24/how-to-build-a-5-star-rating-system-with-wilson-interval-in-mysql/) really well explained calculation but I really don't know if it's correct or not. I've seen a lot of posts on the subject I haven't seen one calculate for 5.

The most important part which is the following code, but I cannot understand the math can't tell if its correct or not.

```
CREATE
TRIGGER `update_rating` BEFORE UPDATE ON `ratings`
FOR EACH ROW
  SET new.total = new.positive + new.negative,
  new.stars = ROUND( (((new.positive / new.total) * 4) + 1) * 2, 0) / 2,
  new.lower_bound = ((new.positive + 1.9208) / (new.positive + new.negative) - 1.96 * SQRT((new.positive * new.negative) / (new.positive + new.negative) + 0.9604) / (new.positive + new.negative)) / (1 + 3.8416 / (new.positive + new.negative))
```

I need to know if it's correct or not. And it be really useful some explanation for how that formula works.

ps: Please do not mark this as a repost, I wrote a similar question but that one was more for sql conversion to c# and did not get the response for sql verification.

Comment: There is no right or wrong way to create a rating calculation. This is a design question, it is up to you what factors you would like to consider and how you would like to weigh these factors to give you the results. Btw, the formulas require primary school level math. Are you truly sure you cannot interpret it?

Comment: Shadow - the formula on link (in a pic) just doesn't seem the same with the formula in the code. Prefered asking instead of making a mistake. If you do not plan to help out why would you even comment. Wasting your time and mine. Also don't recall going over Statistical theories in primary school. If you do great to see you help out on this.

Comment: Your `new.lower_bound`-formula is a 1:1 translation of the lower bound of a 95% confidence interval of the Wilson score, so a specific case of the formula in your picture. The wiki article explains how the statistics work, your link explains how to use it for your 5-star-rating-system. Not sure if anyone can add any information to what's already covered there in less than 5 pages unless you have a very specific question. So if you want to use Wilson score for your ranking, you can use that code. But if you don't trust your link, you can't really trust me either without calculating it yourself.